# Rspec testing a search method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Very new to TDD an I'm trying to test a search method with Rspec but I keep getting

```
expected: "Test project"
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

#### projects_controller.rb

```
def index                                      
  @projects = Project.search(params) 
end
```

#### project.rb

```
def self.search(params = {})
  return find_name(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?

  all
end

scope :find_name, ->(search) { where("name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%") }
```

#### projects_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Project, type: :model do
it "finds a searched project by name" do
    FakeStubRequests.load
    project = create(:project, name: "Test project", database_url: "https://fake-database.firebaseio.com/", secret_key: "FakeSecretKey")
    @result = Project.search(search: project)
    expect(@result).to eq("Test project")
  end
end
```

Comment: You are trying to compare the `@result` (which is an ActiveRecord::Relation object) to a string `"Test project"`. You either need to call `@result.first.name` and compare it to the string or find manually the Project record and compare it to `@result.first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to search by `Test project` and expect `project`, but not vice-versa. But even better, to search by something LIKE `Test project`, for example `roject`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Project, type: :model do
  it "finds a searched project by name" do
    FakeStubRequests.load
    project = create(:project, name: "Test project", database_url: "https://fake-database.firebaseio.com/", secret_key: "FakeSecretKey")
    @result = Project.search(search: "roject")
    expect(@result).to eq([project])
  end
end
```

Comment: `Project.search` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not a `Project` instance.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks I was wondering why  it was returning ActiveRecord and also appreciate your input on searching for a part of the name to actually test its full functionality!